# spree_api/rabl escapes doubleqoutes in jsonp response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, jsonp, spree, rabl

When I make a request to a spree 2.2.0 API (rabl gem version 0.8.4) to

> domain.com/api/products

I get

```
{"count":25,"total_count":26,"current_page":1,"pages":2,"variants":[{"id":1,"name":"Ruby on Rails Tote","sku":"ROR-00011",...  And so on
```

Same thing with JSONP Callback like

> domain.com/api/products?callback=test

gives me

```
test(["{\"count\":25,\"total_count\":26,\"current_page\":1,\"pages\":2,\"variants\":[{... And so on
```

Does anyone have had that strange escaping behaviour before? Any clues, how to get an unescaped response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening an Issue on github, the problem is now resolved:
https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/4332